# Change paragraph font size in bootstrap.css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

we are using bootstrap v2 CSS and we want to increase the font size by a point or two globally. i wanted to know if this was a simple change in the CSS file or more complicated than that.

i tried and looked into the CSS but it's complicated to me and i am afraid of breaking something else. Can someone possibly help with this.

Comment: Don't change bootstrap files, just add a rule in a custom CSS file.

Comment: My suggestion... load the page in a browser with developer tools (i.e Chrome, Firefox with Firebug, etc.).  You can see the CSS applied to any element and edit it in real time.  This will also show you exactly which line of CSS applies.  Play around until you get the setting you like, then make the change in the file/line indicated or add custom CSS to override the style(s) you want to change

Comment: I definitely wouldn't change the bootstrap css files. This will be a nightmare to maintain when new versions come out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you add:

```
<style type="text/css">
p {
   font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
```

to your HTML file (in the header) you're all set.

If that doesn't provide the desired results, add `font-size: 16px !important;` instead.

Important will tell the browser your CSS file is more important than Bootstrap's and it should use yours instead.

Just make sure your CSS file or section (like above) is added after the Bootstrap CSS reference.